# Why do I not get my custom error message in case of "unknown choice for a l3keys.choice"?

Tags: expl3, l3keys, error-writing

I'm trying to issue a custom error message in the case of an unknown choice for a `l3keys` `.choice` key. In the following MCE:

- I created a custom message `Unknown~key~choice`,
- I defined a `key` key which has the `.choice` property,
- I used the special `unknown` choice that should issue an error message based on my custom `Unknown~key~choice` message.

If the supplied key is one (in fact the only one, in this MCE) of the valid values (`key=foo)`, everything works as expected. But, otherwise (e.g. `key=bar`), the issued message isn't my custom one but the `expl3` default one in such a case:

> ! LaTeX Error: Key 'mymodule/key' accepts only a fixed set of choices.
>
> For immediate help type H .
> ...
>
> l.21 }
>
> ? H
>
> The key 'mymodule/key' only accepts predefined values, and 'bar' is not one of
> these.
>
> ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn{mymodule}{Unknown~key~choice}{
  The~ supplied~ value~ `#1`~ for~ `key` isn't~ one~ of~ the~ valid~ ones~ (`foo`).
}
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
  key .choices:nn  = {
    foo ,
    unknown .code:n = {
      \msg_error:nnx {mymodule} {Unknown~key~choice} {\exp_not:n {#1}}
    }
  }{
    You~ have~ chosen~ “\l_keys_choice_tl”!
  }
}
\keys_set:nn { mymodule } {
  % key=foo
  key=bar
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the unknown choice on its own:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn{mymodule}{Unknown~key~choice}{
  The~ supplied~ value~ `#1`~ for~ `key` isn't~ one~ of~ the~ valid~ ones~ (`foo`).
} 

\keys_define:nn { mymodule } 
  { 
   key .choices:nn  = {
     foo ,
    }
    {
      You~ have~ chosen~ “\l_keys_choice_tl”!
    },  
   key / unknown     .code:n = {
      \msg_error:nnx {mymodule} {Unknown~key~choice} {\exp_not:n {#1}}
   } 
  } 

\keys_set:nn { mymodule } { 
  % key=foo
  key=bar
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed. It is not obvious from the documentation...

Comment: well the documentation (and the example later on)  says imho quite clearly that choices:nn is for a list of keys that share the same code.

Comment: Now you clarify this that way, it is much clearer indeed :) But, since there isn't any example with both `.choices:nn` and `unknown .code:n`, it is still not so obvious imho: I thought that the “special `unknown` choice” was so special that it could be used as I tried to do so in my OP.